# React Native - Application Performance Issues With The FlatList?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I completed my application in `react native` but after building its slow. Then I started to research to improve the performance of the application. I found this [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#js-fps-plunges-when-re-rendering-a-view-that-hardly-changes) on the official website of the `react native` and I am sure this will help me but I am unable to get it into my head. Please can anyone tell in easy words what the following documentation is saying:

> If you are using immutable data structures, this would be as simple as a reference equality check.
>
> Similarly, you can implement shouldComponentUpdate and indicate the
>   exact conditions under which you would like the component to
>   re-render. If you write pure components (where the return value of the
>   render function is entirely dependent on props and state), you can
>   leverage PureComponent to do this for you. Once again, immutable data
>   structures are useful to keep this fast -- if you have to do a deep
>   comparison of a large list of objects, it may be that re-rendering
>   your entire component would be quicker, and it would certainly require
>   less code.

I will be glade. Thanks !!!

Comment: So what is rendering slow?  I'm assuming your FlatList, but where are you getting the data from?  What type of data is it?

Comment: static object of some words

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a static object, you can render your component as a PureComponent like it says above.  Then, you can pass it props or set the state with the words you want displayed.

When you do that, the FlatList will re-render only the portions of the data that it needs to, depending on what changed.  What the last part of it is saying is that a PureComponent does shallow comparisons - if something in an array changes, but the array itself doesn't change, then your FlatList won't update.  However, with an immutable object, you can always declare it as a PureComponent and it should be faster.

Comment: what the `table` refers to here?

Comment: yes its more clear now. thank you Scott Sir, too much respect for you !